# Icon format is becoming obsolete?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-runtime, icons

With the arrival of Windows 8 several things have changed in application development, now with the concept of Windows Store Apps (WinRT).
These new applications does not use icons files, but PNG images for the tiles.

With this, it is possible to conclude that the icon file format is becoming, or already has become, obsolete?

I ask this because recently I developed a IconBitmapEncoder for wpf, an encoder to generate icon files. Then came to me this question, if I was investing my time in something that could already be obsolete.

What is your opinion about it?

Comment: The .ico file format supports PNG's: [The evolution of the ICO file format, part 4: PNG images](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/22/10079192.aspx). Besides that, Windows will continue to support Desktop Applications for several years (if not decades) to come.

Comment: Do you have a programming question? Opinion style questions like this generally aren't a good match for StackOverflow. For what it's worth, ICOs have supported embedded PNGs for a number of years as well. It's just a natural progression, and will eventually be obsolete as you mentioned. Eventually.

Comment: Thank you IInspectable and WiredPrairie.

Comment: WiredPrairie, this is my first question on StackOverflow, so thanks for orientation relative to the kind of questions whether should be asked here.

Comment: Twitter is probably one better place to start discussions like these. MSDN maybe. :) Other than that - I'd be interested in finding out about a good forum for technology speculations.

Comment: Ideally a channel discussions of technology speculation focused on programming. Would very helpful, I believe.